# Printing slowly (to mimic typing)

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a text based game and I want the text to print out slowly to simulate typing. I also want it to be an input. Is it possible to do this?

I saw someone else use this code(bolded is what i added):

```
import sys,time

def sinput(str):
  for c in str + '\n':
    sys.stdout.write(c)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(4./90)

slowtest=sinput('Does it work? ')
**if slowtest == 'yes':
    print('Amazing!')**
```

And it was able to print out the code slowly just like I wanted, unfortunately I can not answer the question ("Does it work?").

Comment: NB: No need to import `sys`. You can replace the two lines with `sys.stdout` with a single `print(c, end="", flush=True)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign `input()` to `slowtest`.

`sinput()` function is not returning anything.

Once you print slowly you can use `input()` for `slowtest` variable then check the if condition.

```
import sys,time

def sinput(str):
  for c in str + '\n':
    sys.stdout.write(c)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(4./90)

sinput('Does it work? ')
slowtest = input()
if slowtest == 'yes':
    print('Amazing!')
```

Comment: I have one more question if that's okay. Is it possible to change the speed at the text types for seperate questions. E.g. It will type at 4. for "Does it work? " and 3. for "Will it work? "

Comment: yes, you can change the speed with different values in `time.sleep()`